# Named Entity recognition in Gate using LingPipe

Tags: java, nlp, gate, lingpipe

I'm using `GATE NLP` to process my document, and I want to Use entity names to use as tag candidates 
In Gate there are `OpenNLP` and `LingPipe` 
as I read an answer form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875765/how-to-define-persons-names-in-text-java?rq=1) @Shashikant Kore answer he said

> if you have the sentence "My friend Joe Smith went to the Walmart
>   store", OpenNLP identifies two named entities - "Joe Smith" and
>   "Walmart". I couldn't get it tag "Joe Smith" as Person and "Walmart"
>   as Organization.

and suggests to use `LingPipe` so I used LingPipe that provided in Gate NLP 
like here

```
SerialAnalyserController pipeline = (SerialAnalyserController) Factory.createResource("gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController");
        pipeline.add((ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.lingpipe.TokenizerPR"));
        pipeline.add((ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.lingpipe.NamedEntityRecognizerPR"));
        pipeline.add((ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.lingpipe.POSTaggerPR"));
        pipeline.add((ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.lingpipe.SentenceSplitterPR"));
        Corpus corpus = Factory.newCorpus("SegmenterCorpus");
        Document document = Factory.newDocument(handler.toString());
        corpus.add(document); 
        pipeline.setCorpus(corpus); 
        pipeline.execute();
```

However, when I run my program I have this Exception

> Exception in thread "main" gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException:
>   No model file provided!   at
>   gate.lingpipe.NamedEntityRecognizerPR.init(NamedEntityRecognizerPR.java:55)   at
>   gate.lingpipe.NamedEntityRecognizerPR.init(NamedEntityRecognizerPR.java:55)

whats the meaning by No model file provided ?? 
sorry because I'm asking this question but I'm totally new to this field 
and I just learn about ANNIE and it didn't need any file when I used it to extract the POS tagging 
any help??

Comment: `NamedEntityRecognizer` requires a parameter `model`. Try to test your pipeline in GATE Developer (GUI)  first... But I didn't succeed to make LingPipe NamedEntityRecognizer run. Seems that the plugin is broken in GATE 8.1. Maybe try the mailing list as well.

Comment: yes its seems that the LingPipe plugin is broken it's give me an error that there is no LingPipe exist although its in the gate file *_* ....I'm reading about  Gazetteer to use it I hope to find a java code .....thanx @dedek

Comment: I'm not sure where the gate plugin came from.  It may need a LingPipe model (compiled named entity recognizer trained on a corpus with a given tag set) on the classpath.  If you can look into the gate.lingpipeNamedEntityRecognizerPR code, it may indicate what path it's looking for.  Then you just need to put it on the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it works for me.

I tried `File` -> `Ready Made Applications` -> `LingPipe` -> `LingPipe IE System` in the GATE GUI. And it has been loaded OK.

The working Model was:
`$gatehome$plugins/LingPipe/resources/models/ne-en-news-muc6.AbstractCharLmRescoringChunker`

The full relevant config for `gate.lingpipe.NamedEntityRecognizerPR` was:

```xml
...    
<string>modelFileUrl</string>
<gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/LingPipe/resources/models/ne-en-news-muc6.AbstractCharLmRescoringChunker</urlString>
</gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
...
```

[image: GATE screen clip]

Comment: I'm very grateful that you come back and answer the question :))) ....I will try it now thanx again :))))